# JavaFX can't play mp3 files

Tags: java, audio, javafx

I followed this tutorial: http://what-when-how.com/javafx-2/playing-audio-using-the-media-classes-javafx-2-part-1/

```
package audioVideo;

import java.net.URL;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.media.*;
import javafx.stage.*;

public class AudioPlayer1 extends Application
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        URL resource = getClass().getResource("resources/sample.mp3");
        Media media = new Media(resource.toString());
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
        mediaPlayer.play();

        primaryStage.setTitle("Audio Player 1");
        primaryStage.setWidth(200);
        primaryStage.setHeight(200);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

And I have the appropriate resources folder in the same directory as the respective .class file, but I still can't play the audio. The mp3 file isn't the same one in the tutorial, but I also have a .wav equivalent and found that JavaFX can play *.wav files out of the box but not mp3 files. What's going on?

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04 64-bit via Eclipse. It can't be a resource issue because the .wav file is in the same folder as the .mp3 one, but the former can be played yet the latter can't. Do I need certain dependencies in order for the mp3 file to be played correctly? I can play the mp3 files from Ubuntu directly.

Comment: Can you play mp3 from Ubuntu directly? ( You need the "restricted" codes in order to play mp3; so when ubuntu doesn't play them ... you need to add the corresponding packages before doing that with java)

Comment: Yes, I can play the mp3 files from Ubuntu directly. I'll update the question with that info.

Comment: So, if that is not the problem, how does your "it is not working" actually look like? Is there an exception, messages in the eclipse console, ???

Comment: Can you upload a sample .mp3 for me to try out?

Comment: It doesn't matter what mp3 file it is, I tried numerous. When I run the program I get numerous exceptions: InvocationTargetException, RunTimeException and MediaException. The exceptions state that the media player cannot be created. If I were to pass in a *.wav file instead of a *.mp3 file, there are no exceptions and the program runs fine.

Comment: Ubuntu 15.x isn't yet a [certified system configuration](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html), maybe it will work, maybe it won't (14.x is certified).  You should check your system against the certified requirements and ensure you have correct glib and libav libraries installed. You should include exception traces in your question.  You should also include [media error handling code](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html).

Comment: That's a shame; I can't install Ubuntu 14.x because of bugs that prevent me from working. I guess I'll have to wait until Ubuntu 15.x is supported then.

Answer (score -1):

First, import the following:

```
import java.nio.file.Paths;
```

Then, when you create your media, do the following:

```
Media media = new Media(("yourAudio.fileExtension").toUri().toString());
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
```

That should do the trick (for a mp3 at least).